# Need an algorithm to create google like word search

Tags: perl, tcl

I will explain the problem here.

Suppose i am having list of 1000 words. Say it is a dictionary. User will input some word and it will match with exact match if the word is correct or give the closest match. Just like Google search as we enter something and it gives the closest match.

Algorithm that i thought is

```
Read the word list one by one
split our input word string into characters
take the first word from the list and match character wise
similarly do it for other words in the list
```

I know this is the long way and it will take lot of time. Do anyone know how to implement better algorithm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Sort the words in an array
2. When a word comes in => binary search (log(n)) (we are doing that because if you use a hash table it will be good for direct match but poor for adjacent)
3. If perfect match return it
4. Else compute a [levensthein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of the requested word with the adjacent words and their neighbors (to be defined) and add them to a list of return (if they are satisfying)
5. Return the list of adjacent words selected

Quick and dirty implementation with `/usr/share/dict/words` (you still have to do the levensthein distance part and selection)

DISCLAIMER: Binary search code borrowed from http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=503154

```
open(FILE, "<", "/usr/share/dict/words");
my @lines = <FILE>;
my $word = $ARGV[0];

sub BinSearch
{
    my ($target, $cmp) = @_;
    my @array = @{$_[2]};

    my $posmin = 0;
    my $posmax = $#array;

    return -0.5 if &$cmp (0, \@array, $target) > 0;
    return $#array + 0.5 if &$cmp ($#array, \@array, $target) < 0;

    while (1)
    {
        my $mid = int (($posmin + $posmax) / 2);
        my $result = &$cmp ($mid, \@array, $target);


        if ($result < 0)
        {
            $posmin = $posmax, next if $mid == $posmin && $posmax != $posmin;
            if ($mid == $posmin){
                return "Not found, TODO find close match\n";
            }
            $posmin = $mid;
        }
        elsif ($result > 0)
        {
            $posmax = $posmin, next if $mid == $posmax && $posmax != $posmin;
            if ($mid == $posmax){
                return "Not found, TODO find close match\n"; 
            }
            $posmax = $mid;
        }
        else
        {
            return "Found: ".@array[$mid];
        }
    }
}
sub cmpFunc
{
    my ($index, $arrayRef, $target) = @_;
    my $item = $$arrayRef[$index];
    $item =lc($item);
    $target =lc($target);
    $a =  $item cmp $target;
    return $a;
}

print BinSearch($word."\n", \&cmpFunc, \@lines)."\n";
```

Usage (if the script is called `find_words.pl`):

`perl find_words.pl word`

Where word is the word you want to search for.

Answer (score 4):

A common algorithm for this sort of "fuzzy" word search is [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). It doesn't really find similar words but calculates the similarity of words. This similarity score (or Levenshtein distance) can then be used by a sorting or filter function to select similar words.

How the distance is measured is simple: how many characters need to be changed from the target word to the matched word. For example, a distance of 3 means that the difference between the words are 3 edits (not necessarily characters since it also includes the act of adding and removing characters).

The Rosetta Code site has a listing of Levenshtein distance algorithms implemented in various languages including tcl and perl: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

There is a page on the tcler's wiki that discusses similarity algorithms which includes several implementations of Levenshtein distance: [similarity](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3070)

For perl, there's also a CPAN module that you can use: [Text::Levenshtein](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Levenshtein/Levenshtein.pm)

So in perl you can simply do:

```
use Text::Levenshtein;

my %word_distance;
@word_distance{@dictionary} = distance($word,@dictionary);
```

Then iterate through the `word_distance` hash to find the most similar words.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using a simple binary search to get a neighbourhood of similar words and then using the Levenshtein algorithm to refine is that errors can occur early in the word as well as late; you run the risk of completely missing words where there's an early error. A more effective technique might be to use the Soundex algorithm to create collation keys in your word list so that you search by basic similarity. Then you can use Levenshtein to refine, but weighting that similarity measure by the rarity of words in the underlying source corpus; assuming that users are more likely to want a common word than a rare one is a useful measure.
(This assumes you've got a source corpus, but if you're wanting to emulate Google then you've definitely got to have one of those.)

It might be better to instead look at ways to use some sort of map-reduce mechanism to run a weighted Levenshtein distance metric over the entire set of words. This is more of a “throw hardware at the problem” approach, but avoids the problems associated with potential problems with words getting missed due to the initial filter. Alas, this does mean that you're going to end up with something that can't be pushed as part of a simple piece of software (provisioning systems to support something like this is unlikely to be something that you'd want to foist on a normal user) but it is likely to be practical to deploy behind a service.